# GSON using Volley in Fragment - Errors

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

I am trying to parse JSON using GSON in Fragment using Volley. But I am getting compile time error at two places

1. `new Response.Listener<String>` : Saying Listener cannot be resolved
2. `new Response.ErrorListener()` : Saying ErrorListener cannot be resolved
3. Cannot resolve method "fromJson"

   ```
   public class Gson extends Fragment 
   {

       RecyclerView recyclerView;
       Response responseobj;
       CustomAdapter customAdapter;
       String url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=ed28d2d13805495a9b896ecb0c7b6ed1";
       Gson gson;
       RequestQueue requestQueue;

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {

           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gson, container, false);

           recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.movielist);

           requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() 
           {
                       @Override
                       public void onResponse(String response) 
                       {
                           // Do something with the response

                           gson = new Gson();
                           responseobj = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
                           customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), responseobj.getArticles());
                           recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                       }
                   },
                   new Response.ErrorListener() 
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
                       {
                           // Handle error
                       }
            });

           //returning our layout file
           //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
           requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
           return view;

       }


       @Override
       public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
           super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
           //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
           getActivity().setTitle("GSON Parsing");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Its a better practise to use Retrofit library for json parsing, it is more efficeint and quick

Comment: Check import of `Response.Listener`

Comment: can you pass the Response class code, I think the problem is there,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your Response class, it should be like this according to your link:

```
public class YourResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("source")
    public String source;
    @SerializedName("sortBy")
    public String sortBy;
    @SerializedName("articles")
    public List<Articles> articles;

    public static class Articles {
        @SerializedName("author")
        public String author;
        @SerializedName("title")
        public String title;
        @SerializedName("description")
        public String description;
        @SerializedName("url")
        public String url;
        @SerializedName("urlToImage")
        public String urlToImage;
        @SerializedName("publishedAt")
        public String publishedAt;
    }
}
```

Secondly change your fragment name (maybe u did import error)

```
public class FragmentGson extends Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the message that Reponse.listener can't be resolved, it's probably because it's unknown. Did you correctly add Volley dependency like this `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` and import correctly Volley in your Fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

From the code which you've pasted, I found that `Response responseobj` is referring to the Response class which you have created and imported in your fragment. At the same time, you are using `new Response.Listener<>()` which should be an instance of `Response` class from the volley library. Now if volley's `Response` is not imported, it will show you an error.

It means that you must import `Response` class from volley also. Make sure you've added these two imports.

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
```

Second thing is that, you must change your fragment name from `Gson` to something else. Otherwise it will cause problems